# Extract specific parts of PDF documents

Tags: excel, pdf, converters

i have multiple (30) PDF files, each containig 48-96 pages. The layout of all pages is identical, there are just other contents (numbers, graphs).

Background: These pages are PDF Reports of fibre cable measurements, and I have to sort them by attenuation of the cables. Due to confidential issues, I unfortunatly cannot give an example file.

For verifying these reports, we are doing some control samples, thats why i need the reports sorted. The question now is: How can I export only very specific parts of all pages in all pdf files to some format i can sort?

As already mentioned, it is very specific where the values are located on the page. It is also already "parsed" content, so it is available "as text" in the PDF file, so it is not scanned, no OCR required.

Any help is appreciated. I currently have no idea how to solve that issue, it could be some tool which does something like that, or a programming approach to solve that.

Comment: Just to be sure, those *very specific parts of all pages in all pdf files* are located at identical coordinates in all those files? And as you already have the data *available "as text" in the excel file,* you do not need to export the data from the PDFs anymore, do you?

Comment: Ah, i'm sorry. It is available as text in the PDF file, fixed that typo. Thanks! And yes, these specific text snippets are always located on the very same coordinates of every page.

Comment: What kind of solution do you look for? Are you ready to do some programming? If yes, which language / environments? If you use Java or .Net, you could implement the task using the parser package functionality of e.g. iText(Sharp) (but there also are other good libraries out there).

Comment: Hm, i see i should have put more information in the question. I have no idea how the solution could look like. Maybe Adobe Acrobat can do that (I had no idea), or any other tool. It could also be a programming solution, there i would prefer php, perl or java. I have no real idea and hope to get some input...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you indicate in your comments to the original question, you are prepared to program a solution. I would propose using Java and the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) PDF library. It enables you to extract text from documents as long as the text actually is extractable (you actually can put glyphs into a PDF but drop the mappings from glyphs to characters).

You can find sample code for PDF text extraction with iText in the [ExtractPageContent* samples for chapter 15](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=15) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/). Especially [ExtractPageContentArea](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279) is of interest in your case.

Essentially you only have to take that sample and generalize it too extract the text from multiple areas on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have by now written a small java application, which takes one ore more PDF pages, parses the results given on a set of rectangles and exports the result a number of ways (currently console, text and csv). I have one question: Currently i just placed random rectangles, for testing purposes. How can I extract the x/y coordinates of a text area in a given PDF file? In later steps a small GUI will follow, where a small preview will be shown, allowing to simply "draw" the rectangles... But for this task, which I need to be done by monday, I have to do it manually.

Comment: Okay, I found out by myself. With [GSView](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/) I was able to open a PDF file and get the position of the text elements.

Comment: In general you can retrieve the mediabox of a file which defines the coordinates of the visible page area.