# Java using iText and Extracting from PDF

Tags: java, itext

I followed some previous advice on StackOverflow here ([Extract specific parts of PDF documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123805/extract-specific-parts-of-pdf-documents)) to extract data from PDFs. I have limited programming experience and virtually none with Java (used C++ when I was younger).

After overcoming some newbie difficulty having the right jars available via the buildpath, I have run into what seems to be a define problem. I hope this isn't a stupid question, I've tried for quite some time to get this to work.

Here's the error I receive:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor RegionTextRenderFilter(Rectangle) is undefined
at PDFExtract.PDFExtract.parsePdf(PDFExtract.java:41)
    at PDFExtract.PDFExtract.main(PDFExtract.java:59)

Here is my code:

```
    package PDFExtract;

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.FilteredTextRenderListener;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RegionTextRenderFilter;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderFilter;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;

    public class PDFExtract {

/** The original PDF that will be parsed. */
public static final String PREFACE = "resources/pdfs/preface.pdf";
/** The resulting text file. */
public static final String RESULT = "results/output.txt";

/**
 * Parses a specific area of a PDF to a plain text file.
 * @param pdf the original PDF
 * @param txt the resulting text
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(70, 80, 420, 500);
    RenderFilter filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
        out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy));
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    reader.close();
}

/**
 * Main method.
 * @param    args    no arguments needed
 * @throws DocumentException 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    new PDFExtract().parsePdf(PREFACE, RESULT);
}
    }
```

The error appears on this line "RenderFilter filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);"

Hopefully someone can help me! Again I apologize if this is a stupid question. I tried jumping from a Hello World to this and it's taxing my aged understanding of C++

Comment: Not sure what all libraries you got in your classpath. I can see this constructor available in RegionTextRenderFilter class https://github.com/rabbicse/java/blob/master/MyIText/IText/src/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/RegionTextRenderFilter.java.  In your workspace can you open the RegionTextRenderFilter and see it it really has a constructor that takes a Rectangle ?

Comment: _"After overcoming some newbie difficulty having the right jars available via the buildpath"_ - the recommended way to use iText, is to set it as a Maven dependency and let Maven do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson you linked to the wrong repository. The official repository is https://github.com/itext/itextpdf and the current version of the file you referenced is https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/master/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/RegionTextRenderFilter.java, so it would be great if you could update your comment.

Comment: Andrew, which version of itext do you use?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the help. I had initially tried using Maven to use discrepancies but didn't get very far beyond entering discrepancies that it seemed I couldn't get to link correctly. I had downloaded a trial version of iText and received an XML key, but I couldn't figure out how to access the libraries. After a little Googling, I did find some jars online that I downloaded. The versions appear to be 5.1.0 and 5.4.3 (I tried including the sources as well). I just manually added them to the project's buildpath. 

I'm sorry if this is a dumb answer, I may be out of my element here.

Comment: @mkl sorry I forgot to tag. I'm just really showing my lacking skills.

Comment: @Andrew the current itext 5 version is 5.5.10, and if you combine libraries, e.g. itext and XmlWorker, they should have the same version. For first steps with itext you don't need a trial license, for the start the standard AGPL version should suffice.